# asp.net Membership Get Multiple Users By ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I need to display multiple users for a Sitecore 7.2 web app on an admin page. The ids for the users to be shown are in a database that is separate from the core database (loose relationship with no key constraints). Aside from moving the table that keeps track of these user ids into the core database, is there a good way to get multiple users by id? I only see methods for either getting one user or all users.

Comment: As I understand your have ASP.Net Membership provider configured not on Core database. How transferring some table can help you to get multiple users by id?

Comment: I could probably add this extra table to the core db, make a foreign key relationship with the table that contains users, and sick entity framework on it. I think I'll probably go with Bryan's suggestion and try to create my own provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many is "multiple?"  If it's somewhere between 2-100, I would just write a little utility item that takes the IDs and then loads them one at a time.

If you *really* need to load 100-1000 users at a time... you will probably need to create your own provider.  Sitecore's User API is just a thin wrapper over standard ASP.NET Membership.  And it uses a fairly straightforward provider model.

You will absolutely have to provide your own system if you want access to user **profiles** in any sort of performance-critical context.  The default system is abysmally slow, mostly due to the incredibly odd SQL schema.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the method for getting all users and filter that by your list of ID's (I assume you mean usernames).

```
using System.Web.Security;

string[] userIds = { "username1", "username2", "username3" };

var users = Membership.GetAllUsers()
    .Cast<MembershipUser>()
    .Where(x => userIds.Contains(x.UserName));
```

Comment: I guess that Frontenderman already is able to get all users. "I only see methods for either getting one user or all users."

Comment: There is only a method for getting all users. That's why I'm showing how to filter them.

Comment: I would avoid doing this.  Performance will make it a no-go if you have more than a few thousand users.